# XHTML. Enclose <div> text in paragraphs and convert <br/> to paragraphs with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xhtml

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to convert his XML (which is like XHTML) with XSLT 1.0:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <div>Hello<a href="http://google.com">this is the first</a>line.<p>This the second.<br/>And this the third one.</p></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

to this one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <div>
        <p>Hello<a href="http://google.com">this is the first</a>line.</p>
        <p>This the second.</p>
        <p>And this the third one.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I was thinking of a tree-walk algorithm in XSLT 1.0. What is complicated are e.g. the enclosed `<a>`links. And also existing `<p>` should not be removed.

May somebody help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420736/how-to-split-text-and-preserve-html-tags-xslt-2-0/) there is an identical question. Unfortunately is XSLT 2.0. My answer was close to XSLT 1.0 even if the use of xsl:for-each-group makes the answer XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You will need also a node-set() function to make possible a multi-pass transformation.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete XSLT 1.0 solution -- no extension functions are necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[text() and p]">
  <div>
   <p>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::p or preceding-sibling::p)]"/>
   </p>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="p | p/following-sibling::node()"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p[text() and br]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "p/text()
    [preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::br]
    or
     following-sibling::node()[1][self::br]
    ]">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p/br"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div>Hello
            <a href="http://google.com">this is the first</a>line.
            <p>This the second.<br/>And this the third one.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
   <head/>
   <body>
      <div>
         <p>Hello
            <a href="http://google.com">this is the first</a>line.
            </p>
         <p>This the second.</p>
         <p>And this the third one.</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is amazing, even if OP should better clarify whether p should be created for each br or sentence or point? In the latter case (point) this is not going to work.

Comment: @empo: I don't see anywhere in the question a requirement that text nodes should be split on period (fullstop) characters.

Comment: WOW! This really is amazing!! `<p>` should be created only for each br. Dot does not matter. Just curious: @Dimitre and @empo How did you learned to be so perfect in XSLT? Are you mathematician? Thank you so much!!! I learned alot of XSLT from you both! :-)

Comment: I think I'm very far to be considered perfect in XSLT, either my XSLT knowledge can't be compared to @Dimitre deeper one.

Comment: @therealmarv: You are welcome. I happen to have mathematical education and I think it generally helps for a programmer to be also a mathematician. As for my knowledge of XSLT, it has accumulated for the last 10 years. If you like such stuff, do have a look at my blog and read the FXSL papers at the "Extreme Markup Languages" conference -- links contained in my profile.